# phpMyAdmin slow for small database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a small database (<100 KB when dumped) that will hang in phpMyAdmin when I try to sort by various columns.

Sometimes it hangs when I try to edit columns by directly clicking on their content.

I see the following warnings and wonder if anyone can provide an experienced based explanation or any assistance in improving the interface.

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
> some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click
> here.
>
> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.77 differs from your MySQL server
> version 5.5.10. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: The warning clearly says what you should be doing!! Refer this: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1031012

Comment: @Jacob I will begrudgingly attempt the upgrade since it is the only suggestion so far (I had difficulties previously). I was hoping someone could state with experience that the symptom and the cause were certainly related. Thanks for the kick in the butt.